# Intern: Is it possible to mark a test as pending / disable it?

Tags: intern, leadfoot

How can I disable a functional test in intern other then using comments?
We are using the [Object Interface](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#interface-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inside a test, this.skip().

That will skip the test with an optional message parameter.